# In Bash, how can I log a success message as well as stderr (if any error) in the same file with different prefixes?

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, stderr, logfile

I want to have a function in bash called doLog

on success it would write to a file with a defined message passed as an arg to the function, prefixed by a timestamp.

On failure, instead of taking that message as an argument, it would instead log whatever the error was, from stderr into that file.

That all seems somewhat straightforward in that you could do something akin to:

```
someCmd && doLog "Success Message"
```

or

```
someCmd 2> doLog    #pipe whatever the actual error message is
```

where the function would have a prefix to add the date. Any errors would additionally contain 'ERROR --' before the date. So the log file would look something like:

```
Wed Jul 18 2018 10:19:22 -- Success Message for cmd1 (set by user!)
Wed Jul 18 2018 10:19:24 -- Different Success Message for cmd2 (set by user!)
ERROR -- Wed Jul 18 2018 10:19:25 -- {whatever stderr says about cmd3}
Wed Jul 18 2018 10:19:27 -- Success Message for cmd4 (set by user!)
```

The part i'm struggling with is how do I have

1. Different prefixes based on success and failure in the same function
2. prefix stderr (from within a function.) - seems trivial to append, but prefixing is proving to a be a little more hairy.

I have something like this for doLog, not accounting for stderr yet. Can I just pipe stderr to stdin and then pass that?

```
doLog () {
    echo $(date) -- @a" >> ${someDest}/${someFileName}.log
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to make `doLog` *always* read from standard input. Write any error messages to a temporary file, and have `doLog` read from that in the event of a failure.

```
if someCmd 2> errlog; then echo "Success message" | doLog; else doLog < errlog; fi
```

This can be refactored in a few different ways, but you may need to make some changes to how you handle the standard output of `someCmd`. For example:

```
{ someCmd > output 2>&1 && echo "Success message"; } | doLog
```

Comment: while I get the basics of what you're saying, maybe the one liner throws me off. How would `someCmd 2> errlog` satisfy a condition to do `echo "Success message" | doLog  `? I thought 2> passed stderr only if there was stderr output - what's satisfying that if condition? Although it looks like passing errLog as an arg to to doLog would fix my prefix situation, right? Just trying to understand more of what's going on here - thanks!

Comment: `someCmd` may or may not write anything to its standard error, but if it does, that will go to `errlog` instead of whatever it inherits from its caller (the shell, in this case). Further, the exit status of the command (which is what the `if` statement looks at) is independent of whether or not anything is written to standard error.

Comment: OK @chepner that makes sense. But then what is passing the exit status (0 if success, other numbers for failure?) to the if condition? In plain words you're basically saying  `If exit status = 0 then doLog "Success Message." Else log stderr to errlog` then piping errlog to doLog correct? Also the if encapsulation has to be on each command i want to log, correct?

Comment: All commands produce an exit status. When you write something like `if [ "$foo" = bar ]; then ...; fi`, the `if` is looking at the exit status of the `[` command, which is 0 if the expression is true. In this case, you aren't running `[`, just `someCmd`. (Whether `someCmd` correctly produces a non-zero exit status if there is an error is another question.) And yes, you need to do this for each command.

Comment: OK, thanks for your patience and explanation. Hopefully last question. So my doLog command itself should be fine, it's just the command encapsulation i need to change for each logging  i want to do? `doLog () { echo "$(date) -- $@" >> ${someDest}/${logName}.log }`. I'll probably want to clear out errlog on each command, so im not sticking previous lines in there as well right? Was hoping to wrap the error logging into one nice neat function but doesn't look like there's a way to do that is there? e.g. have the if logic inside the function